# Uniform continuity of a function on closure of a set, where it is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Suppose $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is domain of function $f(x)$ on which it is **uniformly continuous** and $f(x)$ has property that for each $x_0 \in \overline A -A$ , $$\lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x)= \lim_{x \to x_0^+}f(x).$$
>
> Lets extend the domain of $f(x)$ to $\overline A$, by writing $f(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ for each $x_0 \in \overline A -A$ , so that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\overline A$.

**Will $f(x)$ be uniformly continuous on $\overline A$ ?**

If **cardianility** of $\overline A -A$  is **finite**, then it is obviously true, so my question is about **infinite** case.

Comment: Can you clarify that $R$ is the real numbers? I don't know what $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+}$ means otherwise.

Comment: Also, you can produce the $\mathbb{R}$ character with the LaTeX \$\mathbb{R}\$.

Comment: @S.R  $A$ need not be bounded.

Comment: @JonathanZ  Edited

Comment: @S.R : How do both limits exist at the extrema of $\overline{A}$ if $\overline{A}$ is compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Clearly, $f$ continuous and $A$ is dense in $\overline A$. This, together with the fact that $f|_A$ is uniformly continuous, is enough to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall x,y\in A):|x-y|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|< \frac{\varepsilon}2.$$Now let $x,y\in\overline A$ be arbitrary with $|x-y|<\delta$. There are sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$. Since $|x-y|<\delta$, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|x_n-y_n|<\delta$, which implies that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\bigl|f(x_n)-f(y_n)\bigr|<\frac\varepsilon2$. So,$$\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl|f(x_n)-f(y_n)\bigr|\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Using same idea I have proven this for finite cardinality of $ \bar A - A$. But, will this work even when cardinality of $ \bar A - A$ is infinite ?

Comment: @LordKK I had no need to take into account the cardinal of $\overline A\setminus A$.

Comment: That step where you took, $k = min\{n_x,n_y, \delta /3\}$, how can we be sure that the inequality $|x-x'| <k \implies |f(x)-f(x')| < \epsilon /3$, will hold even for $x' \in \bar A - A$. To ensure that, we need to define $k = inf \{n_x : x \in \overline  A - A\}$ and prove that $k > 0$

Comment: @LordKK Note that $x'\in A$. I wrote that.

Comment: Sir, but thats the issue. We need to show uniform continuity on $\overline A$, so that should hold even for $x' \in \overline A - A$

Comment: You are right and I was wrong. I've edited my answer. Please tell me what do you think now.

Comment: Yes. This is great. Thank you.